# converting Flex application to HTML5

Tags: html, apache-flex

I have a flex application to work on an iPad.  What is the best way to convert this application?

Answer (score 0):

Your subject line is a separate question from your post LizaM, but I'm assuming you specifically want to convert a Flex application into HTML5 and not something natively iOS.

If the Flex application is complex and you need to convert to markup that you can work with for further development then you might not have any options other than to get your hands dirty and start from scratch. Good ol AJAX/HTML (or call it HTML5 - whatever sexy words you want to use for the markup you're using to run on Safari).

There are tools out there (e.g. Swiffy and SoThink SWF Decompiler), but I don't think they'll help much if you're trying to convert rich Flex library classes. I could be wrong about this, but that seems to be the state of affairs at the moment.

J

Comment: Swiffy, the Google project does not support ACtionScript 3; so it will be useless when trying to convert a Flex application.  The SoThink Decompiler will only be of help if the poster has none of the original code.  [And if that was the case; why would he be trying to convert it?]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a Flex application to the iPad, you should consider porting it to a Native App. There are plenty of tools and documentation for doing that.

If you create a Flash Builder Mobile Project, you'll have an output option for iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Flex 4.5 can compile your air applications for IOS. Simply use the compile for IOS options.
You can also compile for Android, RIM/Blackberry etc...